# PHP - How to avoid reload a form when change route

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, single-page-application

I have this simple form in `index.php`:

```
<div class="form-container">
    <form id="create-form" action="create.php" method="POST">
      <label for="name">Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
      <br/>
      <label for="score">Amount:</label>
      <input type="number" id="score" name="score">
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" name="addBtn" id="addBtn" value="Add" />
    </form>
</div>
```

What `create.php` contains:

```
<?php
  include 'db.php';
  $name = $_POST["name"];
  $score = $_POST["score"];
  $sql = "insert into demo_table (name, score) values ('$name', '$score')";
  $conn->query($sql);
  $conn->close();
  header("location: index.php");
?>
```

Currently, I have this script in `index.js` using JQuery and AJAX but keeps reloading the page because of the `index.php` call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#create-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'create.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log('agregado');
            location.href = 'index.php';
       }
   });
 });
});
```

Currently this works well, but reloads the page when clicking on the button and when reload the data (last line in `create.php`). What I am trying to do is to implement AJAX and/or JQuery in order to avoid this and have a complete Single Page Application.

Disclaimer: I am starting learning PHP. So, I am making any mistake, please let me know first of all. I will be attentive to your answers.

Comment: There is plenty Ajax examples... Have you tried anything?

Comment: This question was fixed.

Comment: That SQL query is widely open for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements before little bobby tables finds your form

Answer (score 0):

Try to make in comment the code `location.href = 'index.php';` inside the `success` method.
Like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#create-form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'create.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(response)
        {
            console.log('agregado');
           // location.href = 'index.php';
       }
   });
 });
});
```

Comment: I need to update data going to the `index.php` route.